# What is the correct type annotation for this Elm function?

Tags: elm

This code works without the type annotation, but I can't figure out how to annotate the `formView` function. I also don't know if this is a generic function or what this is actually called?

```
import Html exposing (..)
import Html.Attributes exposing (..)
import Html.Events exposing (..)

type Msg = EmailChanged String | PasswordChanged String

formView : String -> msg -> Html Msg
formView label msg = div [] [text (label ++ ": "), input [onInput msg] []]

main = div [] [formView "Email" EmailChanged, formView "Password" PasswordChanged]
```

Comment: What type does the type inferencer infer?

Comment: Ok typed it into the elm REPL and it worked, got `<function> : String -> (String -> msg) -> Html msg`

Answer (score 0):

Using the Elm REPL showed me what the type inferencer infers as suggested by @Jörg W Mittag

The correct type annotation as inferred by the type inferencer is:

```
formView : String -> (String -> msg) -> Html msg
```